# How to store images? (A:indexedDB)

Tags: javascript, database, image

My understanding it that webSQL is being deprecated so I was trying to decide between localStorage, indexedDB, or FileSystem

Which one would be better?  These are just 64px by 64px images normally.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`IndexedDB` is a `no-sql` storage mechanism that is best used for database like applications.  Just convert your images to `Base64` and store them in the key value pairs that `localStorage` provides instead.

Comment: IndexedDB is not the same as localStorage. IndexedDb is intended for large amounts of data and has significant search capbilities. It's probably a bit heavyweight for an image store. localStorage stores short key-value pairs and generally has a size limit of about 5Mb per domain (varies by browser). This might not be enough if you have significant numbers of images to store.

Comment: I realize the difference.  That is why I suggested localStorage for such a simple task.  Should be effective if the images are small.  If they are large then IndexedDB would better.  In fact I don't think the complexity adds much over-head.  Might be a better over all solution as it scales.  Is there a similar limit for IndexedDB?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [jquery-base64](https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64) plugin, Put images as base64 encoded string

```
$.base64.encode( "this is a test" );
$.base64.decode( "dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them straight into a [FileSystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) - no encoding required, or better, add the required manifest files for an [offline app](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) which will work perfectly well online too and let the browser handle the local storage. This has the advantage that no special Javascript code is required to unpack and display the images - just use an image tag with the `src` attribute as normal.

Comment: pretty much none of the popular apps ( facebook, twitter, etc. ) uses "offline app", despite wide support, as it requires user consent.  It's one of those HTML5 APIs that never gets used.

Comment: FileSystem only has support in Chrome as far as modern browsers go.